# ExtJS out of the box docs page

Tags: php, jquery, extjs

I am trying to build out a documentation page for our product. Something like:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#

http://docs.ckeditor.com/

is what I would like to do. These two sites are exactly the same and it looks like they are built with ExtJS. Is this something that can be done with ExtJs without a whole lot of customization? I have never messed with sencha so I am not real familiar with the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are built automatically from the JS source using [JSDuck](https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck).